# Date.ftl - set current time

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm using date.ftl to display date and time in Alfresco Share 4.2c, with parameter showTime set as true. Default time is 00:00. Is there a way to set current local time as the default time?
Is it better to try to change that in date.ftl or maybe in some associated .js file?
I was looking, but I couldn't find where it is set, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: which version of alfresco you are using?

Comment: I'm using  Alfresco Community 4.2c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing existing `date.ftl` is not advisable.Instead of that you should create your own date control(you need to create both ftl and as well as javascript file),In that  you need to change below things.

Change in `tomcat\webapps\share\components\form\date-picker.js` file(this should be file which you have created for your custom control).In onReady() function set the value of text box using javascript.